# central network storage with limitations

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

At my organization we want to have a central storage location where users can share their files. The problem is when they no longer needs these files they forget to delete them and then we end up having a problem of what we can and cant delete.
So we are looking to see if there is a GPO or something that has it where it will automatically be deleted after a period or a way to enforce that the files get deleted when they are no longer in use. 
All of our servers are running 08 R2 SP2.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with dfs or nfs. Please don't use random tags that don't apply.

Comment: How will you know that a file is no longer needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing is first, you need to **clearly** define the criteria that you are using for this. What does `"no longer in use"` mean? Does that mean that the "Last Accessed" attribute is older than a certain number of days? How can you be sure that it's OK to delete? What if it's important archival information that's only needed in the event of something like a tax audit?

A simple batch script using `forfiles.exe` can be written to delete things over X days old, but that's really not normally a good thing to do.

A better thing might be to give individual users quotas. For example, each user can only put 2GB of files onto their share. Once it hits that limit, if they want to add more, they either need to request a quota raise and justify it, or delete older files. The tool that you'd use in 2008 R2 is the `File Server Resource Manager`. It is typically installed with the File and Print Services role.

Comment: I second the user quota - that's what I do and most people really don't need more than 300Mb (in my case) and when they reach it, they normally just remove the old stuff.

Comment: So what happens is our developers share files with each other. But usually it is only needed for a short period of time. So what happens is they upload files to a share but then they never delete them. So it jsut needs to be temporary with a limitation up to a month max that the files would be there until they are deleted.

Comment: MDMarra I do like your idea though that sounds like exactly what I need to do.

Comment: The use `forfiles` on a batch script to delete anything older than 30 days and put it in a scheduled task.